# Are women allowed to have dreadlocks in the Maghreb region?

Tags: international-travel, cultural-awareness, islam, north-africa

My friend and I are planning to travel to the Maghreb region once it is safer to do so. She has fairly long (maybe chest length) dreadlocks and we were wondering if we might run into any issues while there? She grew up in the west but has middle eastern heritage and so without being insulting does have a middle eastern appearance, so perhaps could be mistaken for a local while we are there? One of the first things we thought about are the challenges of wearing a burka or hijab with the long dreadlock hairstyle, since it isn't easy to tie up into a small neat bun for example. Are there any specific things we should think about, or should we rethink our travel?

Comment: You mentioned "Maghreb region" in the question but the title says "middle east". Those are rather different places. Which countries are you planning to visit. specifically?

Comment: I wouldn't worry to much about Burka or Hijab. Only Iran requires a headscarf, and the areas where in Afghanistan where you have to wear a burka you probably do not want to go to anyway...

Comment: On headscarves in Iran: Rick Steves filmed one of his shows there in 2009, and women on the street would pull up their headscarves when they saw the cameras.  But they were not afraid to come up and talk to him with about 25% of their hair still visible.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Uhm, actually depending on the country, now as Chris mentioned, Middle East and Maghreb region are very different culturally.
If you really meant Maghreb (which is the western area of north Africa, notably Morocco and Tunisia) then you have nothing to worry about, you can wear absolutely anything you want.
If you meant Middle East, then it really depends on the country. For example, in Dubai you can be whoever you want, where in Saudi Arabia, it mostly conservative.
I recommend trying YouTube, people are vlogging even in North Korea nowadays.

Comment: Ah I mistook that all Arab League countries were part of the middle east, my mistake. Thank you for your answer: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Member_states_of_the_Arab_League